# Ubuntu 20.04 wake from suspend password removal

Tags: password, wakeup

I couldn't find anything on 20.04 and how to make it not ask for a password when it wakes from suspend.
Can someone help?
Thanks.

I do not find this in settings.

In Settings, under Screen Lock, there is a setting "Lock screen on suspend". If you turn that setting off, you shouldn't be asked for a password on waking up.

Thanks all, the link solved the "problem" and so did the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings, under Screen Lock, there is a setting "Lock screen on suspend". If you turn that setting off, you shouldn't be asked for a password on waking up.